# How to deal with Magento Malware attack?

Tags: admin

Has Magento shared any update regarding how you should to deal with the malware attack?

Comment: Which version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can refer to the following article published by magento: [malware-attacks](https://magento.com/security/best-practices/remediating-your-site-after-malware-attack)

If you find this answer useful please mark it as solution or upvote.